Summation involving product of associated laguerre polynomials
Please help me to evaluate this sum:
$$ \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(l+p)!}\left(a x y\right)^l L_p^l\left(a x^2\right) L_p^l\left(a y^2\right)$$
I found the Hardy-Hille formula on wikipedia which had an additional factorial term in the numerator, which I do not want.
I can identify parts of the summation being related to the generating function and parts of it to the modified Bessel function of the first kind. And then I saw Hardy-Hille formula which had an additional factorial term in the numerator. But beyond these preliminary thoughts, I do not have much idea how to progress.
Motivation:
This summation came up in the context of the physics of Laguerre Gaussian beams and entangled photons which is my main interest. If you consider the spontaneous parametric down-conversion process, then the entangled photons produced by them can be written in the Laguerre-Gaussian basis having two indies, $l$ and $p$. If you sum over all $p$, then you get the Schmidt spectrum. I want to get the radial spectrum by summing over all $l$.
PS: The $L_p^l$ function is the associated Laguerre polynomial, also known as the generalised Laguerre Polynomial. Wikipedia has the definition. In Quantum Optics, the $l$ index denotes Orbital Angular Momentum of the photon and the $p$ index is the radial index.

What did you try? Can you show us your efforts?

Hi, @Dominique. I can identify parts of the summation being related to the generating function and parts of it to the modified Bessel function of the first kind. And then I saw Hardy-Hille formula which had an additional term in the numerator. But beyond these preliminary thoughts, I do not have much idea how to progress. This summation came up in the context of the physics of Laguerre Gaussian beams and entangled photons which is my main interest.

@CraniumClamp Ok. The $L_p^l$ function is the associated Laguerre polynomial, also known as the generalised Laguerre Polynomial. Wikipedia has the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials

p parameter is integer only  or non-integer ?

@MariuszIwaniuk $p$ is a non-negative integer, 0, 1, 2 etc.

@RadhikaPrasad the Hardy-Hille formula would sum over $p$ index, not $l$.

@HugdeRoda I see. Thanks for pointing out. Would something similar exist for $l$ summation? Say for positive integer $l$?
